# change div size using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, size

i have done something like that;

```
    <div id="bloc2" onDblClick="document.getElementById('bloc2').style.height = 200px" style="width: 350px; height: 150px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #000;background-color:#F2F2F2">
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

but it doesn not work
the div is generated using php, here is my code:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM commentaire where n_doss='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['n_doss'])."' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,5";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(__LINE__.mysql_error().$sql); 
?>
    <?php
     $r=0;
     while($donnees2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      ?>
      <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
           <td width="128px">
           <?php if ($donnees2['etat']=="VR") {?>
                <img src="images/wallet.png" />
           <?php } else {?>
                <img src="images/newsletter.png" width="128" height="128" />
           <?php } ?>
           </td>
           <td>
             <div id="bloc<?php echo ++$r ;?>"                  
                  onDblClick="document.getElementById('bloc<?php echo $r ;?>').style.height = 200px" 
                  style="width: 350px; height: 150px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #000;background-color:#F2F2F2">
                <?php echo mb_strtoupper(html_entity_decode($donnees2['commentaire'])) ; ?>
            </div>
```

but nothing works, except mistakes in the console.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
<div id="bloc2" onDblClick="document.getElementById('bloc2').style.height = 200px" style="width: 350px; height: 150px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #000;background-color:#F2F2F2">
```

you have Javascript error:

```
document.getElementById('bloc2').style.height = 200px
```

The 200px should be a string, YOU HAVE TO ADD QUOTES so use this line instead:

```
document.getElementById('bloc2').style.height = '200px'
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null suivi.php:945
ondblclick

Comment: The syntax is correct.. try to move the code into Function and call the function in onDblClick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` keyword and wrap `200px` with quotes

```
<div id="bloc2" onDblClick="this.style.height = '200px'" style="width: 350px; height: 150px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #000;background-color:#F2F2F2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add string "" with 200px

```
<div id="bloc2" onDblClick="document.getElementById('bloc2').style.height = '200px'" style="width: 350px; height: 150px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #000;background-color:#F2F2F2">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rMbYP/)

Comment: now it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null suivi.php:945
ondblclick

Comment: check the demo link and remember who answer first

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="bloc2" 
     onDblClick="this.style.height = '200px'" 
     style="width: 350px; height: 150px; overflow: 
     auto; border: 1px solid #000;background-color:#F2F2F2">

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

</div>
```

Comment: I guess issue is with this line `<?php echo mb_strtoupper(html_entity_decode($donnees2['commentaire'])) ; ?>` because above posted code works fine if you run it as it is, You should check your php div generation logic.